# Firebase realtime database how to filter data based on availibility in web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase database structure of a product.

```
{
  "Available" : "1",
  "BrandID" : "26",
  "ProductID" : "245",
  "ProductImagePath" : "/images/palmolive/refreshing-lemon.png",
  "ProductName" : "Refreshing Lemon Shaving Cream",
  "SubCategoryID" : "23",
  "Variants" : {
    "245_26" : {
      "Available" : "1",
      "MRP" : "55.00",
      "SellPrice" : "54.00",
      "VariantID" : "26"
    },
    "245_42" : {
      "Available" : "1",
      "MRP" : "30.00",
      "SellPrice" : "29.00",
      "VariantID" : "42"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get all the products and their variants where Available = 1 for both. This is code for getting data.

```
var productsRef = firebase.database().ref('products');
productsRef.orderByChild("Available").equalTo("1").once('value', function(snapshot) {

    // dispplay logic

});
```

It gives me all the all products where Available = 1 for products and all variants of that product. I just need only those variants of that product whee Available = 1 not 0.

Can any one help me how to get that?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, As requested, i replaced data image with actual JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query this type of structure with Firebase. As usual with NoSQL databases, you'll have to restructure your data to allow the query your app needs.

So if you want to query product variants by their availability, you should store a list of product variants by/with their availability. There are many ways to do this and the best one depends on your app. Below I'll investigate two of the most popular options:

### Store variants by availability

```
"availability": {
  "Available_1": {
    "245_26": "245/Variants_26",
    "245_42": "245/Variants_42"
  }
}
```

With this you can access all variants with Available=1 with a simple direct lookup:

```
var productsRef = firebase.database().ref('products');
var availabilityRef = firebase.database().ref('availability');
availabilityRef.child("1").once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(variantKey) {
        productsRef.child(variantKey.val()).once('value', function(variantSnapshot) {
          // display available variant in UI
        });
    })
});
```

### Store variants in a list with availabity

Alternatively you could store a long lists of variants with their availability:

```
"variants": {
  "245_26": {
    path: "245/Variants/245_26",
    Available: 1
  },
  "245_42": {
    path: "245/Variants/245_42",
    Available: 1
  }
}
```

This structure you can query with:

```
var productsRef = firebase.database().ref('products');
var variantsRef = firebase.database().ref('variants');
variantsRef.orderBy('Available').equalTo(1).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(variantKey) {
        productsRef.child(variantKey.val().path).once('value', function(variantSnapshot) {
          // display available variant in UI
        });
    })
});
```

This option works great, but is (slightly) more work for the database, since it will have to consider all variants. If you already know you'll need to store hundreds of thousands of items, I recommend the first structure which allows for a direct lookup of all items with a specific availability.